# Why doc and pdf type file can't be uploaded while checking fake images file

Tags: javascript, html

I managed to check whether if user change the file extension manually such as `.exe` to `png or jpg` but how am I going to let user upload doc type file while checking the images whether it's fake or not(User can upload doc and image at the same time).

Here's my code :

```
<div class="row">                           
<div class="col-lg-12">
<label class="fieldlabels">Documentation:</label> 
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="file_name"  onchange="return fileValidation()" name="file_name" value="" title="Documentation" multiple="multiple"/>  
</div>
 </div>

 if (this.vpb_settings.vpb_form_id == "myForm") {
                var files = document.getElementById('file_name');
                for (let i = 0; i < files.files.length; ++i) {
                let fname = files.files.item(i).name;
                if (!isVideo2(fname)) {
                alert("File extension not supported!");
                files.value = '';
                return false;
               }
             }
                // $("#add_files").append(vpb_added_files_displayer);
                // $("#added_class").val(new_classc);
        if (window.FileReader && window.Blob) {
        if (files.files && files.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var img = new Image();
                img.onload = function() {
                    // var preview = document.getElementById('preview');
                    // preview.src = e.target.result;
                    // alert('correct');
                    $("#add_files").append(vpb_added_files_displayer);
                    $("#added_class").val(new_classc);
                    };
                    // alert(img.onerror);
                img.onerror = function() {                  
                    alert('Please choose actual files');
                    files.value='';             
                    // window.location.reload();
                    return false;                       
                    };
                img.src = e.target.result;                              
                }
            reader.readAsDataURL(files.files[0]);
            }
        }   
}
```

I managed to check the file whether is fake or not but when i upload for doc / pdf it will always pop out a message asking for user to choose an actual files.How am I going to just check the images while not affecting the doc type files.Thanks in advance.